# How to use if-else statement for solving a system of differential equations using odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to use odeint to solve a system of equations in state-space form using `odeint`.when I run this code, I just get the plot for one condition only.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import zeros

X=np.array([[0],[0],[0],[0]])
X1=np.array([[0],[0],[0],[0]])
U= np.array([[vin],[vdon]])
```

defining A1,A0,B1,B0

```
  def conv(X,t):
        sw=0
        if condition
            statement

        else:
            statement
        return xdot

    X0=np.array([0,0,0,0])
    t=np.arange(0,.0005,10**-8)
    t1=np.arange(.0005,.001,10**-8)
    for i in range(1,2):
        vin=12
        X=odeint(conv,X0,t)
        vin=-12
        X1=odeint(conv,X[-1],t1) 
    Xplot=np.concatenate((X,X1))
    tplot=np.concatenate((t,t1))
    plt.plot(tplot,Xplot)
```

Comment: Your code seems to plot the full t,t1 and full X,X1.  t is going from 0 to .0005 and t1 from .0005 to .001 .  You could plot them separately as `plt.plot(t, X)` and `plt.plot(t1, X1)`

Comment: Apart from that, `for i in range(1,2)` seems to just repeat the same thing twice, so I think you can remove it. `sw=0` inside `conv` probably needs to be removed and replaced by `global sw` to tell Python that `sw` is defined in the global scope.

Comment: I need both the plots in one figure only.Also the plot that I get using `plt.plot(t1, X1)` isn't correct.I've added the picture of the desired plot that I need in the question above.I have obtained the plot using Euler.But using odeint doesn't give me the right plot.

Comment: But the plot that I'm getting for `plt.plot(t1, X1)` isn't correct. I tried doing the code in `solve_ivp` but ran into some `indexerror`

Comment: When `vin=12`(line 5) is removed, it gives the plot that I actually need in `t1` range.The plot that is obtained from the code above is needed in the `t` range

Comment: After each change to `vin` you need to execute `U= np.array([[vin],[vdon]])`. If you just remove `vin=12` in line 5, you should get an error.

Comment: Yes, it worked! A big thanks. One last help, could you help me to execute the same code using `sol_ivp`

Comment: I understand too little about the equations. Also this sw=0 looks very weird to me. Maybe you could ask a new question so somebody else could jump in? (Also please leave out the `for i in range(1,2):` as that just wastes time.)

Comment: I made the changes.here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763178/indexerror-index-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-1-while-solving-a-syst